# Ingresar SOLO números en c++ y llamar de nuevo si falla

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Estoy intentando lograr una función que obligue al usuario a ingresar solo números pero que al mismo tiempo si no es un numero vuelva a la misma funcion.

```
int cin_number_int() {
    int number;
    cout << "Ingresar SOLO números"
    cin >> number;

    if(typeid(cin).name() !== 'int') {
        number = cin_number_int();
    } else {
        return number;
    }
}
```

gracias por adelantado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Bienvenido a stackoverflow!

Te comparto una solución que tengo aplicada en un proyecto personal y que me funciona bastante bien.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int cin_number_int() 
{
    int input;
    while (!(cin >> input)) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Entered value is not a number, please introduce number" << endl;
    }

    return input;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Ingresar SOLO números" << endl;
    int number;
    number = cin_number_int();
    cout << "El número es" << number << endl;
}
```

Esta función comprobará si el valor ingresado es un número (tipo int) en caso de no serlo repetirá la operación (gracias al while) hasta que el usuario ingrese un número correcto. No olvides agregar el `#include <iostream>` al comienzo de tu programa.

Como enriquecimiento adicional, puedes usar esta función haciendo uso de la misma estructura expuesta para ingresar valores de forma repetitiva, previa comprobación por el usuario

```
int new_number;
char answer = 'y';
do {
    new_number = cin_number_int();
    cout << "Require new number? [Yy/Nn]" << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    answer = tolower(answer);
} while (answer == 'y');
```

Este último fragmento podría estar contenido en una nueva función que sea por ejemplo, "solicitar número con validación" y así enriquecer el comportamiento e interación del usuario.

Espero que te ayude.

Saludos!